# Typescript 1.1.0-1 and void 0

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript **1.0.0**, the following code:

```
public static renderView(req, res, options: any = {}, view: any = false){}
```

Generated the following output:

```
Controller.renderView = function (req, res, options, view) {
    if (typeof options === "undefined") { options = {}; }
    if (typeof view === "undefined") { view = false; }
}
```

Now, using **1.1.0-1**, it generates this:

```
Controller.renderView = function (req, res, options, view) {
   if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
   if (view === void 0) { view = false; }
}
```

I've never seen this kind of `void 0` stuff. It seems to work correctly but I'd like to understand what's happening under the scene.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked to close this topic.

Comment: @Vadorequest - you should be able to delete your question.